# Identify cause of high GHC memory consumption without profile build

Tags: ghc

I heard GHC is slow in terms of LOC per second. So I created this Haskell program:

```
module Main where
x1 = 1
x2 = 2
x3 = 3
...
x999998 = 999998
x999999 = 999999
x1000000 = 1000000
main = putStrLn "1M LOC!"
```

And I can't even compile it! At least I can see that parser can do 43 lines per second:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( 1Mloc.hs, 1Mloc.o )
*** Parser [Main]:
Parser [Main]: alloc=22735369056 time=23683.420
```

As far as I know, GHC RTS must be recompiled with profiling enabled to start digging into the cause. Given I don't have profiled GHC, is there any chance to figure out what is causing this? I can't even collect statistics because it gets killed...

```
Killed process 16609 (ghc) total-vm:1074093288kB, anon-rss:6804448kB ...
```

Actually, I can't compile 10K LOC either. With down to 1K LOC at least I can see horrible productivity numbers. I realize this is a synthetic program, but what could be so bad about it?

```
Linking 1Kloc ...
   1,383,344,416 bytes allocated in the heap
     325,164,408 bytes copied during GC
      60,849,840 bytes maximum residency (9 sample(s))
         282,960 bytes maximum slop
              58 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       233 colls,     0 par    0.227s   0.230s     0.0010s    0.0066s
  Gen  1         9 colls,     0 par    0.149s   0.174s     0.0193s    0.0588s

  TASKS: 4 (1 bound, 3 peak workers (3 total), using -N1)

  SPARKS: 0(0 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.000s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.522s  (  1.047s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.376s  (  0.404s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.000s  (  0.008s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.899s  (  1.460s elapsed)

  Alloc rate    2,647,974,824 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  58.1% of total user, 71.7% of total elapsed
```